# Interval optimization with length inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, inequality, optimization

What is the largest constant $c$ such that for any integrable function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ with $\int_0^1 fdx = 1$, it is possible to divide $[0,1]$ into five intervals $I_1,\dots,I_5$ (from left to right) such that

- $|I_j|+|I_{j+2}| \ge |I_{j+1}|$ for $j=1,2,3$ ($|\cdot|$ denotes the length of the interval).
- $\int_{I_j}f dx \ge c$ for $j=1,\dots,5$?

Without the first condition, the answer is clearly $c = 1/5$. With the first condition, by starting with the $c = 1/5$ solution and modifying it to fit the condition, it looks like getting $c = 1/10$ is possible, although this does not seem to be the right answer.

Comment: If $|I_i|=|I_j|$ for $i,j\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ then the inequality holds and $I_j=1/5$ and $\int_{I_j}f=1/5$ if $f=1$.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit about the modification to get $1/10$?

Comment: @Zim Starting with the $c=1/5$ solution, for each $I_j = [x_j,y_j]$, let $z_j=x_j$ if the left half has more value, and $z_j=y_j$ otherwise. The new $j$th interval will be $[\frac{z_{j-1}+z_j}{2}, \frac{z_j+z_{j+1}}{2}]$ (with the exception of the first and last intervals, which start at $0$ and end at $1$ respectively).

Comment: Interesting, so sort-of a bisection-method approach. So the question is, can we find the largest $c>1/5$ though, right?

Comment: @Zim That's right.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: @A.Pesare Not necessarily

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts / partial answer: the function $f$ below sets a limit of $c \le 1/6$.

- Define $Z = (0.1, 0.9)$.  I chose $Z$ to stand for *Zero*.
- $f(x) = 5$ for $x \notin Z$.
- $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in Z$.

So this function has two narrow parts ("end zones") with area $= 1/2$ each, one on each end.  Consider the four boundary points (besides $0,1$).

- If two of them are in $Z$ then the min area $= \min_i \int_{I_i} f\ dx = 0$.
- If none of them is in $Z$ then we cannot meet the first constraint unless all four of them are in the same end zone.  This limits the min area to $1/8$.
- If one of them is in $Z$ then the best we can do is to have two in the one end zone and one in the other.  By having $3$ intervals in one of the end zones, this limits the min area to $1/6$.

Comment: hi ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: hi @mathworker21 - long time no chat!  i've been very busy at work in past N months...